# Back up multiple databases to the same backup (BAK) file with encryption

Tags: sql-server, backup, encryption

I have a script that we run on an ad-hoc basis that grabs the names of 15 databases, then iterates through that list to backup each one into a single .BAK file.  This is then downloaded for use elsewhere (e.g. development).  The key part of the TSQL script is as follows:

```
WHILE @current <= @end
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(50) = (SELECT DatabaseName FROM #DbList WHERE (OrderId = @current));
    DECLARE @backupFile nvarchar(200) = N'D:\Backups\' + @dateString + '_All.bak';  
    BACKUP DATABASE @dbName TO DISK = @backupFile WITH 
         COMPRESSION
        ,COPY_ONLY;
    SET @current = @current + 1;
END
```

This works great, but now I'd like to add encryption into the mix.  Following tutorials on creating a SMK, a DMK and a certificate my code now becomes this:

```
    BACKUP DATABASE @dbName TO DISK = @backupFile WITH 
         COMPRESSION
        ,COPY_ONLY
        ,ENCRYPTION (ALGORITHM = AES_256, SERVER CERTIFICATE = MySQLBackupCertificate);
```

However, when executed only the first database in the list backs up, every other database gets an error, e.g.:

> Processed 9856 pages for database 'DatabaseName01', file
> 'DatabaseName01_Data' on file 1.
>
> Processed 2 pages for database
> 'DatabaseName01', file 'DatabaseName01_Log' on file 1.
>
> BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 9858 pages in 0.401 seconds (192.049 MB/sec).
>
> Msg 3095, Level 16, State 1, Line 33 The backup cannot be performed
> because 'ENCRYPTION' was requested after the media was formatted with
> an incompatible structure. To append to this media set, either omit
> 'ENCRYPTION' or create a new media set by using WITH FORMAT in your
> BACKUP statement. If you use WITH FORMAT on an existing media set, all
> its backup sets will be overwritten.

From my searches there are some things I can't decipher, namely:

1. Because I'm using the same certificate to encrypt each database, the error confuses me
2. I cannot use `WITH FORMAT` otherwise each previous database will get wiped

I fully understand that **my approach may be flawed** (I don't know what I don't know and it's not through lack of reading!).  I've only been able to find answers and tutorials that relate to multiple databases; single BAKs, but nothing also related to encryption.

Can anyone please advise the correct approach to save multiple databases to a single backup file (if indeed it is possible)?

Comment: You can't append an encrypted backup to a non-encrypted backup set.

Comment: But what part is not encrypted?  This is the first part of my question; the encryption parameter is used for each database in the iteration so I don't understand the context of the error.  Or do I need to somehow encrypt the backup set before iterating the database names please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But what part is not encrypted? This is the first part of my question; the encryption parameter is used for each database in the iteration so I don't understand the context of the error.

That's my fault, I just looked at the error and didn't read much else :| Apologies.

> Can anyone please advise the correct approach to save multiple databases to a single backup file (if indeed it is possible)?

It is a [current restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16#Restrictions).

> Appending to an existing backup set option is not supported for encrypted backups.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  I must've become tutorial-blind today when reading up...